# Does the ink usage differs when printing jpeg and tiff image.

Tags: printing, jpeg, tiff

I printed two files one in a tiff format and another in a jpeg format. My question is will there by any difference in Quantity of ink used for both or in other ways will JPEG or Tiff consume more ink ?

Comment: How could there be any difference?

Comment: As a TIFF and JPEG might have slightly different pixels due to compression, there might be a difference. But it will depend on the image, and any difference in ink usage is probably not significant... In any case, I believe this is off-topic for SO, as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i'll bite. The file format themselves have no effect.That which could cause differences:

A) The application used to print the file.
B) The format of the file. A CMYK TIFF or JPEG might print differently than the same image in an RGB TIFF or YCbCr JPEG.